# Create 'number of matches' list using python

Tags: python, regex, list, text

I have text in a file in this format:

```
[NP mr. speaker ] , [NP mr. vice president ] , [NP members ] [PP of ] [NP congress ] [NP my fellow ] [VP americans ] : [NP today ]
```

I want to obtain a list showing the number of matches with NP in it, in descending order. To be clear, there might be many NPs in the text, [NP mr. speaker] might occur 5 times in the text, [NP mr. vice president] might occur 6 times in the text... and so on. I want to find the frequency of all such matches.

The output should be like so:

```
6 [NP mr. vice president ]

5 [NP mr. speaker ]
```

etc.

Any ideas how to go about this? I'm pretty sure regex in python will help but I'm lost on what my expression should look like and how to put those matches in a list.

Comment: Is using python a requirement, or just something you thought might help you?

Comment: python not a requirement, shell tools could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for python here, basic shell tools are all you need.

```
grep -o '\[NP[^]]*]' input.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
```

If you need to check for `NP` in the middle of the braces, you'll need to tweak that slightly

```
grep -o '\[[^]]*NP[^]]*]' test.in | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
```

Comment: `%` is the command prompt, you'll probably see a `$` instead. Don't include it.

Comment: thanks the first one worked, but its not giving it in descending order of number of matches, from what I can see its ascending order according to alphabet...

Comment: For order you just need to add `| sort -rg` at the end.

Comment: tried that, didnt work so i appended `| sort -rn -k1 > input.text.countsorted` and it output a text file with the correct order!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` and `Counter` in python:

```
In [150]: from collections import Counter
     ...: import re
     ...: s='[NP mr. speaker ] , [NP mr. vice president ] , [NP members ] [PP of ] [NP congress ] [NP my fellow ] [VP americans ] : [NP today ]'
     ...: c=Counter(re.findall('\[[ .\w]*\]', s))
     ...: 

In [152]: c['[NP mr. speaker ]']
Out[152]: 1
```

To sort the keys in a descending order:

```
In [156]: sorted(c, key=c.get, reverse=True)
Out[156]: 
['[NP members ]',
 '[NP mr. speaker ]',
 '[NP congress ]',
 '[PP of ]',
 '[VP americans ]',
 '[NP my fellow ]',
 '[NP mr. vice president ]',
 '[NP today ]']
```